# How do you show 1-forms are differentials of functions?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am taking a differential geometry course and over 90% of the class doesn't understand the lecturer (the lecturer is a phd student and doesn't understand what we know already) , I was hoping someone can explain to me what you need to do to show that a one-form is or isn't a differential of a function, Thanks.

Given a 1-form such as $\alpha = x^2x^1 dx^1 - x^3x^2 dx^2 + x^3 x^1 dx^3$

How can you show $\alpha$ is or is not a differential of a function?

Note: the one-form is in 3-dimensional real space with coordinates $(x^1,x^2,x^3)$

Thanks for the help.

Comment: For $\alpha$ to be a differential, it's necessary that $d\alpha=0$.

Comment: Just in case it's helpful to you, you might want to check out my lectures on YouTube covering stuff on differential forms, Stokes's Theorem, etc. (See my profile for the link.) Not any advanced differential geometry, though, sorry.

Comment: I saw one of your lectures last night I'm sure, similar surname, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can always proceed naively by supposing there is such a function, say, $f(x, y, z)$, differentiating to compute $df = \sum f_{x^a} \,dx^a$, comparing like coefficients, and solving the resulting p.d.e.

In the case of the example function, comparing the $dx^1$ coefficients gives $f_{x^1} = x^1 x^2$, so integrating gives $f(x^1, x^2, x^3) = \frac{1}{2} (x^1)^2 x^2 + g(x^2, x^3)$ for some $g$. Now, what does comparing the other coefficients give?

As Lord Shark the Known pointed out in a comment under the original question, if $\alpha = df$ for some $f$, then $d\alpha = d^2 f = 0$, giving a necessary condition for $\alpha$ to be a differential of a function. This has the advantage that the check requires only differentiation, not integration. In our case, we have
$d\alpha = -x^1 dx^1 \wedge dx^2 + x^2 dx^2 \wedge dx^3 + x^3 dx^1 \wedge dx^3 \neq 0$, so we can conclude immediately that $\alpha$ is not exact. This necessary condition is also *sufficient* if the domain of $\alpha$ is simply connected, but otherwise it need not be.